# Sharing a Connection Among Threads

Tags: database, multithreading, database-connection, derby

From Derby development guide "[Pitfalls of sharing a connection among threads](http://download.oracle.com/javadb/10.3.3.0/devguide/cdevconcepts89498.html)", it is good practice to assign each thread to a distinct connection. I would like to know the behavior "If one thread commits, it closes the Statements and ResultSets of all other threads using the same connection" is true among all RDBMS or just Derby?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact behaviour will depend on the RDBMS used, but the vast majority will either

- do the same as Derby
- not support multiple threads using the same connection at all (i.e. it may crash or produce other undefined behaviour if the same connection is used from multiple threads).